# Documentation on Prana PIV's "ID, Sizing & Tracking" Tab

Tags: matlab, imaging

I am currently working with Prana PIV (Particle Image Velocimetry).
At some point they added the section "ID, Sizing and Tracking" to the GUI. I can't find any documentation or manual on this section and how these settings influence the results of the PIV analysis.

I would be glad if you could provide me with some links or literature (maybe a manual) on this topic.

Greetings Stephan

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.researchgate.net/publication/229346607_Methods_for_Digital_Particle_Image_Sizing_%28DPIS%29_Comparisons_and_improvements - this code is primarily based on this publication, if you follow the rabbit hole of citations you should find the other literature that you need.